# Python sympy ignoring multiplication

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I am trying to convert an equation to latex format and rendering it to Matplotlib.
First I used [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to simplify and convert it to latex using the [latex](https://github.com/mbr/latex) function. However, the latex output does not work.

```
from sympy import simplify, latex

equation = 'NIR * (red ** 4.26 /rededge ** 5.21) + (rededge/ red) ** 3.23'
print (simplify(equation))
# NIR*red**4.26/rededge**5.21 + (rededge/red)**3.23
equation_latex = latex(simplify(equation))
print (equation_latex)
# \frac{NIR red^{4.26}}{rededge^{5.21}} + \left(\frac{rededge}{red}\right)^{3.23}
```

As you can see in the image below, the `NIR` and `red` variables have no space, event though  I wanted x or * sign that represent multiplication to be there.

Is there any workaround or did I miss anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read `help(latex)` to understand how to customize its output. There are many keyword arguments that can be set. For your specific case, you need to set `mul_symbol` to any of these values: `None`, `ldot`, `dot`, or `times`.

Also note that there are two similarly named Sympy functions:

- `sympify`: Converts an arbitrary expression to a type that can be used inside SymPy.
- `simplify`: Simplifies the given expression.

I believe that you were aiming for the first one.

Back to your example:

```py
from sympy import sympify, latex
equation = 'NIR * (red ** 4.26 /rededge ** 5.21) + (rededge/ red) ** 3.23'
equation_latex = latex(sympify(equation), mul_symbol="dot")
print(equation_latex)
# out: \frac{NIR \cdot red^{4.26}}{rededge^{5.21}} + \left(\frac{rededge}{red}\right)^{3.23}
```